# Error "Cleartext communication not permitted" in emulator in React-native project

Tags: react-native

I made a project in React Native.  After loading into the android emulator (in Android Studio in Windows 10), the application does not see the development server.  I entered localhost:8081 in the settings.  If I go to this address from a browser in the emulator, then the development server page opens normally.  That is, the Metro works and there is access to it from the emulator.  But it is not available from the application - if I click on the Reload option in the development menu, a message appears that the development server is not available.  If I click on Debug, a message appears Failed to connect to debugger CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy. How to fix it?

React-native 70.0

In emulator Android 9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native android connect backend service at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206456/react-native-android-connect-backend-service-at-localhost)